# WP custom data (not blog entries)?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

What is the term used by WP for custom data that appears on the website. For example, the site needs testimonials which include the following: photo, name, testimonial, link. How are these fields defined in WP and how to loop over them in the frontend?

I'm new to WP. In ExpressionEngine, this concept is called "Channels". What's the equivalent in WP?

Comment: Are you trying to add client testimonials as post and show them frontend ?

Comment: Client testimonials was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create all of that photo, name, testimonial, link inside of a Custom Post Types you can read more about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types)

Comment: Can I attach a list of "tags" for a custom post type? For example, say the custom post type was a web project and I wanted to tag them with one or more of the following: "web design", "logo design", "web development", etc. I would like these tags to be customizable, too, like custom post type.

Comment: yes, you have tags and categories aka taxonomies on custom post types